# Flutter Android build failing because of some artifact issue (Failed to transform activity)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am getting this error again and again not able to know what might be the issue
here is the console log which i am getting again and again

This application is an old one i am updating it to become null safety
All of this is working fine for iOS but giving issue in android

Flutter version: 3.3.7 (using this as i have updated this before )

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform activity-1.6.1.aar (androidx.activity:activity:1.6.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-assets, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /Users/moiz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.activity/activity/1.6.1/23139afb40f2e445f869f2a5f07eb056b1661a3c/activity-1.6.1.aar.
         > Failed to transform '/Users/moiz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.activity/activity/1.6.1/23139afb40f2e445f869f2a5f07eb056b1661a3c/activity-1.6.1.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
   > Failed to transform annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar (androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-assets, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /Users/moiz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation-experimental/1.3.0/5087c6f545117dcd474e69e1a93cacec9d7334af/annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar.
         > Failed to transform '/Users/moiz/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation-experimental/1.3.0/5087c6f545117dcd474e69e1a93cacec9d7334af/annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12m 29s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Here is the app level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is the scr/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.geethen.timeumpire"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
}
```

I have tried android gradle update

`./gradlew clean`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this
i have re created the android folder and updated all the dependencies

the main issue here was regarding the dependencies were incompatible and because of that it was not updating to the latest

Check all the dependency and update to latest you will get the issue solved