# Flutter Build Failing ( Android Transforming Activity failed)

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, androidx, android-jetifier

I am getting this build error. I have done gradle cache rebuild, flutter clean and pub get but still no progress. My application uses flutter_simple_Edge_detetion [as available here.](https://www.flutterclutter.dev/flutter/tutorials/implementing-edge-detection-in-flutter/2020/1509/) Since the author is not supporting the package further I am using dart version **2.10.5** and flutter version **3.7.1**.

I know that this is a dependency issue as stated in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75873502/flutter-android-build-failing-because-of-some-artifact-issue-failed-to-transfor). However the answer is not very much descriptive and clear.
This is my error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform activity-1.6.1.aar (androidx.activity:activity:1.6.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-assets, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.activity\activity\1.6.1\23139afb40f2e445f869f2a5f07eb056b1661a3c\activity-1.6.1.aar.
         > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.activity\activity\1.6.1\23139afb40f2e445f869f2a5f07eb056b1661a3c\activity-1.6.1.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
   > Failed to transform activity-1.6.1.aar (androidx.activity:activity:1.6.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-assets, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.activity\activity\1.6.1\23139afb40f2e445f869f2a5f07eb056b1661a3c\activity-1.6.1.aar.
         > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.activity\activity\1.6.1\23139afb40f2e445f869f2a5f07eb056b1661a3c\activity-1.6.1.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
   > Failed to transform annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar (androidx.annotation:annotation-experimental:1.3.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-assets, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.annotation\annotation-experimental\1.3.0\5087c6f545117dcd474e69e1a93cacec9d7334af\annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar.
         > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.annotation\annotation-experimental\1.3.0\5087c6f545117dcd474e69e1a93cacec9d7334af\annotation-experimental-1.3.0.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: null. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Following is my pubspeck.yaml file:

```
name: temp
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.10.5 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  camera: ^0.10.0+1
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  image_picker: 0.8.7+4
  image_picker_android: 0.8.6+11
  permission_handler: ^10.0.0
  flutter_speed_dial: ^6.0.0
  mobile_scanner: ^2.0.0
  flutter_vibrate: ^1.3.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
  url_launcher: 6.1.6
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  css_filter: ^1.0.2
  photofilters: ^3.0.1
  provider: ^6.0.4
  reorderable_grid: ^1.0.5
  pinch_zoom_release_unzoom: ^0.0.10
  overlay_loading_progress: ^1.0.0
  hidable: 1.0.3
  flutter_image_compress: ^1.1.3
  flutter_isolate: ^2.0.4
  wakelock: ^0.6.2
  draggable_scrollbar: ^0.1.0
  #  pdf: ^3.8.4
  share_extend: ^2.0.0
  alh_pdf_view: 1.2.0
  external_path: ^1.0.3
  search_page: ^2.2.0
  animated_icon: 0.0.4
  printing: 5.9.3
  firebase_core: 2.8.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.2.4
  firebase_storage: ^11.0.10
  firebase_storage_web: ^3.3.19
  cloud_firestore: ^4.3.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.2
  flutter_signin_button: ^2.0.0
  connectivity_plus: ^3.0.2
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.2
  simple_animations: 1.3.3
  animate_gradient: ^0.0.2
  lottie: ^1.4.0
  ionicons: ^0.2.1
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  sqflite: 2.2.3
  uuid: ^3.0.7
  intl: ^0.17.0
  path: ^1.8.2
  shared_preferences: 2.0.17
  pdfx: ^2.3.0
  animated_toggle_switch: ^0.6.1
  percent_indicator: ^4.2.2
  share_plus: ^4.5.3
  package_info: ^0.4.0+16
  firebase_remote_config: ^3.0.13
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.2.0
  bulleted_list: ^0.0.1+0.1a
  google_nav_bar: ^5.0.6
  google_fonts: ^4.0.3
  animated_text: ^1.0.2
  video_player: ^2.6.0
  cloud_functions: ^4.0.13
  scratcher: ^2.3.0
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.6
  google_mobile_ads: ^2.4.0
  flutter_countdown_timer: ^4.1.0
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.16
  awesome_notifications: ^0.6.21
  simple_edge_detection:
    path: C:/Users/Admin/StudioProjects/flutter-simple-edge-detection

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/
    - assets/
    - assets/fonts/
```

Here is the project level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is the app\build.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
    }

    compileSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.compileSdkVersion').toInteger()
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.temp"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion').toInteger()
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm-linux-androideabi'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'}
```

My gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

I have tried cleaning gradle cache, updated my flutter version from 3.3.9 to 3.2.1 but can't seem to figure out how to solve this issue. Any more information required then please tell.

Any answer will be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was due to my dependencies in my flutter project. Specifically, when I observed the pubspeck.lock file, then there was an image_picker_android package. Due to the version 0.8.6+15, the flutter.dev team had upgraded the androidx.activity from 1.6.1 to 1.7.0, [as you can see here.](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker_android/changelog)

So to sum it up, I downgraded this dependency, and changed some other dependencies' versions and the error is gone now.

Note that there were other dependencies too which were causing an error but not the specific error which I posted in the question.
Happy coding!